# Get individual Id for every item in list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a list view with one item for this moment.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        SelectionMode="Single">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" Something to identify item individually ??? />

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

        <Button Text="Commencer" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="StartProcessButton"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I want to get an id or name or something who can individually get this item in my viewModel.

For example If I have an id system on this item :

```
void Action() {
  if (listView.itemSelected.id == 1) {
     then ....
  }
}
```

I'm looking for this kind of thing. I checked google but I didn't found something for me.

Comment: You could add a GUID to your item's viewmodels and search for these then. By the way what do you want to accomplish by making the items in your list searchable (via an ID)

Comment: Please provide your ItemsSource for the ListView. As @MouseOnMars points out it is as simple as adding a GUID as a property or in simple words adding an Index property to the Item model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a id property.

Contact.cs

```
public class Contacts
   {
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string address;

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

    private string image;

    public string Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set { image = value; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <ListView
    x:Name="ContactsList"
    IsVisible="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ItemSelected="ContactsList_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Source="{Binding Image}"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Address}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Contacts> myList;

    public ObservableCollection<Contacts> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
        set { myList = value; }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Id = i, Name = "Student" + i.ToString(), Address = "Address" + i.ToString(), Image = "usa.png" });
        }

        ContactsList.ItemsSource = MyList;
    }


    private void ContactsList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Contacts)e.SelectedItem;
        if (item.Id == 1)
        {
            //.......do something you want
             DisplayAlert("Id", "the id of item is 1", "Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

In the ContactsList_ItemSelected event, you could get the ID from the e.SelectedItem. I use DisplayAlert to show the result.

[image]

Comment: Ty nice example !